# Storing a String saved as a Variable in a MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, ruby, twilio

In a ruby script that sends information to the TWILIO API, I have a string of characters of characters that their (Twilio's) API outputs. I then have the console output it so I can save it as a variable and reuse it later:

> `@client = Twilio::REST:Client.new account_sid, auth_token`
>
> `call = @client.account.calls.create({:from => 'incoming', :to => 'outgoing', :url => 'url', :method => 'GET'})`
>
> `puts call.sid`

This part is functional, but now when I rename the variable (// @incoming_Cid=call.sid //) as to input it into a MySQL database, I bump into an issue. (The 34 character ID has numbers and letters, so I define the datatype as VARCHAR).

> `begin`
>
> `dbh = DBI.connect("DBI:Mysql:db_name:localhost",
>                   "user", "pass")`
>
> `dbh.do ("INSERT INTO calls (column_name)"` #//Select the column to insert
>
> `"VALUES (incoming_Cid)")` #Insert the 34 character string.
>
> `dbh.commit`
>
> `puts "Customer SID has been recorded"`
>
> `rescue`
>
> `puts "A database occurred"`
>
> `puts "Error code:    #{e.err}"`
>
> `puts "Error message: #{e.errstr}"`
>
> `ensure`
>
> `dbh.disconnect if dbh`
>
> `end`

Right here at the **dbh.do ("INSERT INTO calls "** line if I put the **incoming_Cid** variable in the ***VALUES()*** instead of seeing a 34-char-string, like *CA9321a83241035b4c3d3e7a4f7aa6970d*, I literally see '**incoming_Cid**' appear in the database when I execute `select * in calls`.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: `"VALUES (#{@incoming_Cid})"` perhaps?

Comment: Of course the #{variable_name} for variables, silly me... Thank you so much!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use string interpolation: `"VALUES (#{@incoming_Cid})"`